# Why can't Tomcat and Spring see my jsp file?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat, model-view-controller

I started learning Spring MVC.I connected all required dependencies with maven and downloaded Tomcat.But when i run Tomcat my jsp file is not opening. What the problem? Annotations seem to be correct

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ildar" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>spring-cource-mvc</display-name>
     <absolute-ordering />
  <servlet>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Controller class:

```
      @Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showMyView(){
        return "first-view";
    }
}
```

And when I run Tomcat , i just see eror 404 not found in browser

Comment: your dispatcher seems to be mapped to `/dispatcher` but the URL you are hitting is `/Spring_MVC/`  - can you see if it works by pointing your browser to `/dispatcher` ?

Comment: still not working

Comment: You need to find out what context your application is being deployed.. did you try the root context (`/`) as well?

Comment: Honestly,I just started learning JSP/MVC today and I don't understand what you talked about

Comment: my bad, you did say you were new at this... let's start with basics, shall we? - please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question.  It's a lot faster to answer if you add code instead of images of code to your question (since one can copy/paste the code to reproduce the issue)